# Not able to get minima of function using symbolic math toolbox

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I am trying to calculate minima of one energy function with variable `t` using Symbolic Math toolbox of Matlab. Here is the code where I am facing the problem. In order to check whether there is minima or maxima, I am also plotting the energy. Unfortunately I cannot post the image because I do not have 10 reputations. Anyway,in the graph I can see that is minima at around `t=0.5331` but the solver returns `0x0 empty matrix`! Please help me understanding this problem! Also suggest me any other method to solve such kind of equations with variables.Thank you!

```
figure(2); 
ezplot(Energy);
dEnergy=diff(Energy);
t_star=solve(dEnergy,t);
```

Comment: What is Energy, what is dEnergy?

Comment: Energy is a function of t and dEnergy is its derivative.

Comment: Please include the full code, including the definition of `Energy` etc., so we can actually try to run the code.